# How to create next & previous from a array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I would like to show the array item in one by one fashion with next & previous similar to slideshow.
When my page loads i am storing data from my db in this  way->## Heading ## 
 `var sampleTags = <?php echo json_encode($query); ?>;`

i.e

`var sampleTags = ["quote 1", "quote 2", "quote 3","quote 4", "quote 5", "quote 6", "quote 7"];`

So, now i would like to show one by one item from  this ( `sampleTags`) array , with previous and next link.

For this i tried:

main point for next is:

```
curIdx = (curIdx+1) / max;
```

and previous:

```
 curIdx = (curIdx+max-1) / max;
```

But i don'nt know why its not working

here is link [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GtVN/1/)
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Show your code that you try

Comment: @Dineshkani sir, i know javascript little bit only. I don't know how to take a item from my above list using javascript/jquery code. Currently, in my mind nothing javascript code is coming to implement this. That's the reason , i did not shown any code in my above question

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is example that could help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/ndFGL/

main point for next is:

```
 curIdx = (curIdx+1) % max;
```

and previous:

```
 curIdx = (curIdx+max-1) % max;
```

Comment: Actually
 its easy. I learn a new thing from your side. Thank you for your support.